IIS double hop issue - but only from one computer
I am a developer for a small business.  One of the apps I wrote is an asp.NET web app hosted on an in-house IIS server.  This app uses windows authentication and impersonation for permissions to an in-house SQL server.  All users are on windows machines and log in using Active Directory accounts in the same Domain.
The app was working fine until a few weeks ago when one user reported they were getting the following error message:

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

All other users are still able to access the app without a problem.  I tried logging into the problematic user's AD account on another computer and I do not get an error.  Likewise I tried logging into the problematic user's computer using a different AD account and I DO get the error.  I tried accessing the WhoAmI.aspx page and it has NEGOTIATE (KERBEROS) as the AUTH_TYPE and shows the user's AD account, so it is in fact passing the windows credentials (at least on the first hop).  Clearly the issue is confined to that one computer, not the AD account or any of the servers.
This user has not received a new computer, but I did notice they recently upgraded to the new Windows 11 24H2 that was just released.  I am not aware of any changes to the code nor to AD nor to any Group Polices for this user.  In the past I have had issues with the Windows Credential Guard causing issues with double-hops; I checked and Credential Guard is NOT enabled on the problematic computer.
This a appears to be a double hop issue but I am a developer so this is all outside of my area of expertise.  I am not sure what could be causing the issue or what to investigate next.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
